# python define a variable in an if statement

Tags: python, variables, if-statement, coin-flipping

I want to make a coin toss / dice roll in python but i cannot figure out how to define / change a variable inside an if statement.

```
import random
def roll(number):
    if(number==1):
        {print("Take a moment to think that through")}
    if(number==2):
        {b=random.randint(0,1)
        if(b=0):
            {ba=1}
        else:
            {bb=1}
        }
```

the part, `{b=random.randint(0,1)}` the `=` is highlighted red and marked as a syntax error. I also tried this:

```
import random
b=0
def roll(number):
    if(number==1):
        {print("Take a moment to think that through")}
    if(number==2):
        {b+=random.randint(0,1)
        if(b=0):
            {ba=1}
        else:
            {bb=1}
        }
```

that gives the same error, and the = is highlighted, not the +

and before you ask, the function roll(number) is called in the shell. the shell is my interface.

Comment: So you know: the `{` and `}` are not needed in Python.

Comment: python use block indentations not curly braces to define scope

Answer (score 3):

```
import random
def roll(number):
    if number==1:
        print("Take a moment to think that through")
    if number==2:
        b=random.randint(0,1)
        if b==0:
            ba=1
        else:
            bb=1
```

Python doesn't use curly braces, you should write your codes like this.Also you have to *return* something in your function.This is  how you can use your function/variables with another methods.

```
import random
def roll(number):
    if number==1:
        my_string="Take a moment to think that through"
        return my_string
    if number==2:
        b=random.randint(0,1)
        if b==0:
            ba=1
        else:
            bb=1
        return ba,bb
```

Something like this, I don't know your whole code so.

Answer (score -1):

You should also think about what should happen if someone enters, for example, roll(15).

```
import random
def roll(number):
    if number==1:
        print("Take a moment to think that through")
    elif number==2:
        b=random.randint(0,1)
        if b==0:
            ba=1
        else:
            bb=1
    else:
        print("What should happen in this case?")
```

Also, @grrr: `if b==0`

Comment: Yes, I just copy-pasted OP's codes so didn't realize that, thanks for warning.

Comment: Yeah, no problem, I'm still mising 2 rep to comment on other people's posts so I had to inform you this way. @grrr

Comment: Here +10 from me then :-)